# Maximum possible quantifier depth in FO$^k$ i.e First Order Logic with $k$ variables?

Tags: first-order-logic

I have just always assumed that the quantifier depth of a function free Fist Order Logic language has to be bounded above by the number of variables in that language. Is this assumption correct ? If not can anyone give a counter example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, restricting the number of variables does **not** set a bound on quantifier depth.

In the context of finite-variable logics, variable *reuse* is generally permitted. (Or rather: variable reuse is generally permitted but unimportant in first-order logic in general, but when restricting the number of variables it becomes important that we're permitting variable reuse.) Permitting such reuse obviously allows formulas and sentences of arbitrary quantifier depth.

For example, the expression

$$\forall x\exists y(P(x,y)\wedge \forall x(Q(y,x))$$

is a well-formed sentence equivalent to the perhaps-more-pleasant

$$\forall x\exists y(P(x,y)\wedge\forall z(Q(y,z)).$$

See the beginning of Chapter $11$ of Libkin's [*Elements of finite model theory*](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/fmt/fmt.pdf) for an example of how permitting this sort of reuse leads to a rich theory. Specifically, Libkin shows how graph connectivity can be expressed as a three-variable infinitary first-order sentence, the key point being that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can express $\varphi_n(x,y)\equiv$ "the distance between $x$ and $y$ is at most $n$" as a three-variable first-order formula via judicious variable reuse. The quantifier depth of $\varphi_n$ is $2n-2$.